# Reuse Excel VBA without importing it

Tags: excel, vba

I created a new macro by recoding my actions. It is used to delete columns from an excel file. If I have to run this macro on excel file that I download from the web, I have to import the macro in visual basic and then run it.

Can I somehow make this macro available to excel so I can run it to all the excel files that I download from a site, without importing the macro in visual basic first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save macros to your personal workbook: http://excelhints.com/2010/11/29/how-to-use-your-personal-macro-workbook/

Macros saved in this way are available to other workbooks.