# vba, include functions like c++(or many other languages)

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have recently started working on lots of vba/excel work. Coming from python/sas/c++ environment I am having some issues getting comfortable with the methodology.
Realizing I am using same macros copying and pasting from one workbook to another I was hoping to create a library of macros and just like many other languages include these in workbooks I create.

For example. I have a script to create a file:

```
sub createfile(path as string)
' Create or overwrite the file.
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fso.CreateTextFile(path, True)
end sub
```

Whenever I write a new macro I want to include this script (or some other script I wrote) instead of copy pasting it.
like

```
include C:\Directory\script.vb
```

at the new workbook.

Is there a way to do this so I can be more organized?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810092/reuse-an-excel-macro-without-importing-it) you are looking for?

Comment: +1 @PankajJaju as this is the easiest way to achieve what the OP wants. From me: if you're coming from other languages you can actually create libraries in your native language and export it as a *.dll. then you can add references to that dll in Excel via COM and use them as a library. Something like [**THIS**](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/c-and-vba/how-to-securely-store-string-connection-in-vba-projects/)